# How to diagnose warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm getting an annoying MSB3277 warning when I build my project. I increased verbosity to "detailed" and I was able to get the following information from the log:

```
      There was a conflict between "Pathoschild.Http.Client, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "Pathoschild.Http.Client, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".
         "Pathoschild.Http.Client, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" was chosen because it was primary and "Pathoschild.Http.Client, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" was not.

         References which depend on "Pathoschild.Http.Client, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" [C:\Users\desau\.nuget\packages\pathoschild.http.fluentclient\3.0.0\lib\netstandard1.3\Pathoschild.Http.Client.dll].
             C:\Users\desau\.nuget\packages\pathoschild.http.fluentclient\3.0.0\lib\netstandard1.3\Pathoschild.Http.Client.dll
               Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\desau\.nuget\packages\pathoschild.http.fluentclient\3.0.0\lib\netstandard1.3\Pathoschild.Http.Client.dll".
                 C:\Users\desau\.nuget\packages\pathoschild.http.fluentclient\3.0.0\lib\netstandard1.3\Pathoschild.Http.Client.dll

         References which depend on "Pathoschild.Http.Client, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" [].
             C:\Users\desau\.nuget\packages\stronggrid\0.30.0\lib\netstandard1.3\StrongGrid.dll
               Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\desau\.nuget\packages\stronggrid\0.30.0\lib\netstandard1.3\StrongGrid.dll".
                 C:\Users\desau\.nuget\packages\stronggrid\0.30.0\lib\netstandard1.3\StrongGrid.dll
```

If I understand this log correctly, it's telling me that my project references Pathoschild.Http.Client version 3.0 and also version 3.1. I understand the reference to version 3.1 because my project references a nuget package called StrongGrid which itself references Pathoschild version 3.1

But I fail to understand where the reference to version 3.0 comes from.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and MSBuild 15 in case that's helpful information.

Comment: Are you using VS 2017 version 15.3 and the .NET Core SDK 2.0.0? (released in august) - they should contain the necessary conflict resolution logic

Comment: VS 2017 Version 15.3.5 and when building from command prompt, it simply says `Building with tools version "15.0"`

Comment: Running `dotnet --info`: `.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0)`

Comment: Sorry I just read `Http.Client` and thought It was the recurring issue of netstasndard libs at the moment.  This is a different library and two NuGet packages depending on different versions of the same assembly.

Comment: As far as I know, I am only referencing one nuget package which references Pathoschild.Http.Client version 3.1 I don't see where the reference to version 3.0 is and the log doesn't name the second package (unless I'm not reading the log correctly).

Comment: Does upgrading `pathoschild.http.fluentclient` to `3.1.0` via nuget package manager help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155948/discussion-between-desautelsj-and-martin-ullrich).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this issue is that the `StrongGrid` package is authored incorrectly.

The version `0.30` of `StrongGrid` is built against version `3.1.0` of `Pathoschild.Http.FluentClient`, but their `.nuspec` file used for creating the NuGet package still lists version `3.0.0` as dependency, so the consuming project will fetch an older version, creating a conflict that cannot be resolved.

To work around this problem, you can explicitly reference version `3.1.0` of `Pathoschild.Http.FluentClient` by adding a package reference to the csproj file to override the version.