# Nuget package version conflict .net core though having same version

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

I am using **.Net core 3.1**. I have a business library project having an assembly(dll) reference of shared library project. Both the project has `nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions Version="2.2.0"`.

But Ι am getting below warnings for version conflict.

> Warning   MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of
> "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" that could not be resolved.
> These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log
> verbosity is set to detailed.

> Warning   MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of
> "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

> Warning   MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

when i enable the detailed verbosity.I got the below. there is no http.abstraction version of 3.1 nuget package but getting below.

There was a conflict between "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
1>        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.
1>        References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\be7573.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll].
1>            C:\Users\be7573.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll
1>              Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\be7573.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll".
1>                C:\Users\be7573.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll
1>        References which depend on "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
1>            C:\Projects\ADFS Auth insync\src\Assemblies\CustPortal.Core.dll
1>              Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Projects\ADFS Auth insync\src\Assemblies\CustPortal.Core.dll".
1>                CustPortal.Core

Comment: Have you tried setting the log verbosity to detailed? Does it give any additional information?

Comment: No. I could not find any detail in it.

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569524/how-to-diagnose-warning-msb3277-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-t

Comment: Updated question with the verbosity details.There is no Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions Version=3.1. wonder how it has come.

Comment: Can you post a minimal project and source file with these references that shows these warnings?

Comment: I removed the nuget package reference and added below in the business libarary.                            But is that good to below reference in class library?                                
         <ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
 </ItemGroup>

Answer (score 1):

Removing nuget reference and adding framework reference solved the issue.

Edit the Project file and look for these entries typically with old version numbers:

```
<ItemGroup> <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" /> </ItemGroup>
```