# Error stating 'found conflicts between different versions of "System.Core" that could not be resolved', would anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, build-error, software-packaging

[image: Screenshot of errors]

I'm trying to build a C# WinForms App in VS 2019 and after packaging, I'm getting an error stating 'found conflicts between different versions of "System.Core" that could not be resolved'. I built the app originally in VS 2015 but have opened it in this version as it gives the ability to package applications. I have just packaged it in preparation for posting on Microsoft Store but it is showing these 2 errors when attempting to build.

Comment: Did you increase the log verbosity to see more details? What does the detailed info show? You can alter log verbosity via Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build And Run > MSBuild project build log file verbosity.

Comment: Regsrding the MSB3277 **warning**, see [How to diagnose warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569524/how-to-diagnose-warning-msb3277-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-t), however the **error** you're getting is clearly telling you to increase the .Net framework version

Comment: I have set the log verbosity to the highest setting @DeMaki but where do I find the build log?

Comment: And @stuartd how would I increase the .Net framework version?

Comment: Project settings / Application / Target Version

Comment: '@stuartd sorry im pretty new to this and I cant find that. I've got options but cant find those settings in there? where would I find project settings?

Comment: @oscar1424 Project -> Properties -> Application -> Target framework

Comment: @oscar1424 you can find the build logs in the Output view. In the menu bar on top of Visual Studio go to View > Output. In this output window you have drowdown where you can select Build among other options like Tests, Source control etc.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.targets(653,5): error : Project must have a reference to an application. Please add a reference under the 'Applications' node in the Solution Explorer.
Done executing task "CreateWapProjPackageFiles" -- FAILED.
Done building target "_ConvertItems" in project "CheckersGame.wapproj" -- FAILED. thanks very much @DeMaki this is what I found that jumped out at me when I looked in the build logs

Comment: thanks very much @stuartd I tried that and set it to .NET Framework 4.7.2 instead which fixed the previous error but seems to have brought about a new error of "Project must have a reference to an application. Please add a reference under the 'Applications' node in the Solution Explorer." in "MSBuild\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.targets".

Comment: got it with your help thanks very much @KyleWang